# Console : SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters when Shrink navbar

Tags: javascript

I know some people already asked for similar questions, but I didn't find an answer for my case. Sorry if I should not have done this.

So I'm learning Javascript, and when I want to do something that would shrink my Navbar, I have this error in my console : SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any solutions...
Here is my code :

```
function HeightBackground(){
  height = $(window).height();
  $("#cover").css({
    'height': height
  })
}
function ShrinkNavbar(){
  $(window).scroll(function({
    if($window.scrollTop() > 50){
      $("#navbar").removeClass('full');
      $("#navbar").addClass('shrink');
    }else{
      $("#navbar").removeClass('shrink');
      $("#navbar").addClass('full');
    }
  }))
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  HeightBackground();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    HeightBackground();
  })
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    ShrinkNavbar();
  })
})
```

Comment: `function({…})` is a syntax error, yes.

Comment: I corrected it but I have now an another error which is : ReferenceError: $window is not defined

Comment: Well, yes it is. Did you mean `$(window)` like in all the other places?

Answer (score 1):

Your closing paren for the callback in the `scroll` event in `ShrinkNavbar` is too far down at the end of the function. The parameter list was never closed properly:

```
function ShrinkNavbar(){
  $(window).scroll(function({ // <- here
    // ...
  })) // <- and here
}
```

Here's the fixed version:

```
function ShrinkNavbar(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    // ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Please vote to close as a typographical error instead of answering.

Comment: Huh. Didn't even know that's a thing.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I have this in my console with your corrected code : ReferenceError: $window is not defined :(

Comment: Sounds like you removed the parentheses around the word `window` too. It's `$(window)`, not `$window` (unless you're secretly also using Angularjs)

Comment: I actually removed the $ and It's working! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function HeightBackground() {
    height = $(window).height();
    $("#cover").css({
        'height': height
    })
}
function ShrinkNavbar() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("#navbar").removeClass('full');
            $("#navbar").addClass('shrink');
        } else {
            $("#navbar").removeClass('shrink');
            $("#navbar").addClass('full');
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    HeightBackground();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        HeightBackground();
    })
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        ShrinkNavbar();
    })
})
```

here is new code.....I hope it's work

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I have this in my console with your corrected code : ReferenceError: $window is not defined

Comment: remove the dollar sign without dollar sign it's working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I don't why, the class for my navbar isn't changing to the Shrink class :c

Comment: show me your HTML code. I think navbar is id, not a class

Comment: Hi, try to remove the class attribute and add class attribute may be its work. and use this $(window).scrollTop()

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar full" id="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-logo">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <a href="" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="">Biography</a>
    <a href="">News</a>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
<header id="cover">
  <div class="bg-cover">
  </div>
</header>
<section class="content">
</section>
</body>
</html>
```